# Как установить aiogram 3.0 на linux

Tags: linux, aiogram

Пожалуйста, подскажите, почему я не могу установить `aiogram` версии `3.0.0` на линуксе?

```
root@blahblah:/home/# pip3 install aiogram==3.0.0
Collecting aiogram==3.0.0
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement aiogram==3.0.0 (from versions: 0.1, 0.2b1, 0.3b1, 0.3, 0.3.2, 0.3.3, 0.3.4, 0.4, 0.4.1, 0.4.2, 0.4.3, 1.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.0.3, 1.0.4, 1.1, 1.2, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.2.3, 1.3, 1.3.1, 1.3.2, 1.3.3, 1.4, 2.0, 2.0.1, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5, 2.5.1, 2.5.2, 2.5.3, 2.6, 2.6.1, 2.7, 2.8, 2.9, 2.9.2, 2.10, 2.10.1, 2.11, 2.11.1, 2.11.2, 2.12, 2.12.1, 2.13, 2.14, 2.14.1, 2.14.2, 2.14.3, 2.15, 2.16, 2.17, 2.17.1, 2.18, 2.19, 2.20, 2.21, 2.22, 2.22.1, 2.22.2, 2.23, 2.23.1, 2.24, 2.25, 2.25.1, 2.25.2)
No matching distribution found for aiogram==3.0.0
```

Comment: На каком линуксе? Какая версия питона?

Comment: @andreymal Debian 10 "Buster" [x64], python 3.7.3

Comment: А, ну ясненько, пошёл питон обновлю, спасибо)